# Cannot draw GMSPolyline with Google Map SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

i'm using below code Json "routes" fetch 3 result but not draw any result 
can't understand way polylines not draw on map, google service working fine and fetch results with all location details but same issue not showing any thing on map still empty map just show my current location. check any one my code and tell me my issue

```
 NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *directionsAPI = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
NSString *directionsUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving", directionsAPI, originString, destinationString];
NSURL *directionsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsUrlString];


NSURLSessionDataTask *fetchDirectionsTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:directionsUrl completionHandler:
                                             ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                             {
                                                 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                                 if(error)
                                                 {
                                                     if(completionHandler)
                                                     completionHandler(nil);
                                                     return;
                                                 }

                                                 NSArray *routesArray = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

                                                 GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
                                                 if ([routesArray count] > 0)
                                                 {
                                                     NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
                                                     NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
                                                     NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
                                                     GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
                                                     polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                                                     polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];


                                                     if(polyline)
                                                     polyline.map = self.mapView;

                                                 }

                                                 // run completionHandler on main thread
                                                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                     if(completionHandler)
                                                     completionHandler(polyline);
                                                 });
                                             }];
[fetchDirectionsTask resume];
```

Comment: Does the map load correctly?

Comment: yes current location show properly and marker show on right place